# Intellij maven project - depends on another maven module with a pull request to other module - issues for which code is seen in the project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pull-request

Running Intellij for a maven project X - depends on another maven module A.

I need to make a change in module A - so create an Intellij project for A and then submit a pull request to that project, but it is has not been accepted yet.

Now I want to make changes to project X that use the change from module A. So OK I can copy the .iml from project A and add it to project X temporarily until the pull request to A is accepted. Also I create a dependency on module A for all modules in X. Also make sure that this dependency is at the top of the list.

The problem is that there is that the maven dependency to A seems to override the .iml module dependency and there are compile errors if I try to use the new functionality in A.

Any way to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

Install project A locally and be sure that the version that X references is updated.

You can install project A locally by using `mvn clean install`, and then you don't have to fiddle with anything related to project configuration.